# Rails: cannot submit a remote form that was loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

### Goal

I have a page with a list of items, coming from a Rails backend. I want to be able to edit a row in that list, using Ajax calls via Rails UJS.

### Approach

I've added an edit button to the end of each row. The edit button is a 
`link_to ... :remote => true`. Clicking it loads the list again, but with the selected
row in edit mode. The editable row is embedded in a `form ... :remote => true`.
The save button in that row is a `submit` button.

**index.html.haml**

```
#editor
  %table
    - @items.each do |item|
      %tr
        = render :partial => 'row', :locals => { :item => item }
```

**_row.html.haml**

```
... 
%td // a number of columns with attributes
...
%td
  = link_to t("actions.edit"), edit_item_path(item), :remote => true
  = link_to t("actions.delete"), item_path(item), :remote => true, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }
```

**edit.html.haml**

```
#editor
  %table
    - @items.each do |item|
      %tr
        - if item == @item
          = form_for @item, :url => item_path(@item), :remote => true, do |f|
            = render :partial => "row_form", :locals => { :f => f }
        - else
          = render :partial => 'row', :locals => { :item => item }
```

**_row_form.html.haml**

```
... 
%td // a number of columns with editable attributes
...
%td
  %button{ :type => "submit" }=t("actions.save")
  = link_to t("actions.cancel"), items_path, :remote => true
```

**Ajax response handling**

```
$("#editor").on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  $("#editor").html($(data).find("#editor").html());
});
```

### Problem

When I load a list page in edit mode `/items/12/edit`, the row of item 12 is 
editable. Clicking the save button submits the form via Ajax correctly and loads
the `/items` index partial, replacing the editable list with jQuery. Clicking 
the edit button again, loads the edit page again (e.g. `/items/12/edit`), with 
the embedded form. Only this time, the form does not get submitted anymore when 
the save button is clicked. It seems the submit event handler is not attached to the 
dynamically loaded remote form.

### Question

How can I submit a remote form loaded via Ajax, preferrably using the Rails UJS approach?

### Duplicates

I know there are duplicates of this question, but none of them were answered. I hope someone finally comes up with a definite answer.

- [Rails remote form loaded via Ajax after document ready is not submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548852/rails-remote-form-loaded-via-ajax-after-document-ready-is-not-submitting)
- [:remote => true/data-remote on a form loaded via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272778/remote-true-data-remote-on-a-form-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: Do you get any errors in your dev tools window?  If so, what are they?  Also, if you haven't already, I would download [RailsPanel](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/railspanel/gjpfobpafnhjhbajcjgccbbdofdckggg?hl=en-US) if you are using Chrome.  It provides some pretty good feedback on your rails requests that you make.

Comment: Looking at your section entitled **Ajax response handling**, I think you might want to try and use event delegation like they exemplify at the bottom of [this page](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  This, of course, would mean you would need to use a class attribute instead of an id attribute to identify your edit form, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem! Thanks to the hints in the answers of both @Jake Smith and @Parandroid. Here's what I found in two steps.

### Finding 1

While getting the `ajax:success` to be fired did not seem to be the problem, it did look like the form handling did not work 100% correctly just on the `$("#editor")` selector. At the very least that needed to be `$("#editor form")`, but that might not work if we start from the index page, which doesn't contain the form yet. So the approach suggested by @Jake Smith seemed to be the most robust way to go after all. This resulted in:

**edit.html.haml**

```
#editor
  = render :partial => "edit"
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('#editor').html('<%= escape_javascript render("edit") %>');
```

**_edit.html.haml (still not working)**

```
%table
  - @items.each do |item|
    %tr
      - if item == @item
        = form_for @item, :url => item_path(@item), :remote => true, do |f|
          = render :partial => "row_form", :locals => { :f => f }
      - else
        = render :partial => 'row', :locals => { :item => item }
```

But still this did not result in a working submit button. Until I discovered what went wrong...

### Finding 2

The solution above did give the submit button plain old `POST` behavior, which the server did not like, since it expected a `PUT` to reach the `update` action. Rails does this by generating a hidden `_method` field with the value `PUT`. I found out that rails generates this field (and a couple of other crucial hidden fields) **on the very top** of the `_edit.html.haml` partial and **not** inside the `form` tag! So I moved the form to the top of the partial and it worked!

**_edit.html.haml (WORKING!)**

```
= form_for @item, :url => item_path(@item), :remote => true, do |f|
  %table
    - @items.each do |item|
      %tr
        - if item == @item
          = render :partial => "row_form", :locals => { :f => f }
        - else
          = render :partial => 'row', :locals => { :item => item }
```

Who would have guessed...

Comment: Your problem is due to html rules of not allowing the placing of a form inside of a table. That's why you had to move your form_for outside of it. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table

Comment: I'd like to add that I had the same issue with a plain rails from (you know all that stuff with haml and simple forms is quite distructing for those who do not use it). My form was wrapped into some divs, so after removing this wrappings, it magically started working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that DOM was modified by javascript and callbacks (on ajax success in your example) was initialized only on DOM init. So when DOM changed (in part of #editor) callbacks didnt work.

So you shoul re-initialize this callback any time you change the DOM with javascript

```
$("#editor").on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  $("#editor").html($(data).find("#editor").html());
});
```

Some time ago jQuery had function called "live". It worked like "on" but tracked the DOM changings. But in current version of jQuery this function is deprecated cause it was slow.

Hope you understand my bad English =)

Answer (score 2):

The way I've gotten this to work is to use the built in Rails functionality for this:

1. In your controller's edit action, add to the `respond_to` block the line `format.js`.  This allows you to create an **edit.js.erb** file that you can use to load the edit form into your DOM.
2. Then in your update action of the same controller, again add `format.js` to the `respond_to` block, and have an **update.js.erb** file that does the necessary DOM manipulation via jQuery.

I'm sure this is explained further in tutorials online, but where I finally understood how it worked without having to call jquery ajax methods was at [CodeSchool.com](http://www.codeschool.com).

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?  Do you know how far this approach got until it stopped working?

Comment: So just go ahead and link to the codeschool root domain as that is totally useful ... eh no.

Comment: Probably not for you.  But the intent was for that link to provide the starting place for them to get signed up, and find the course they would want to take.  If I linked to a particular course, they'd have to sign up anyway.  But thanks for your useful comment there.

Comment: No problemo, any time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this one whereby a form that was loaded in via ajax was not being submitted, this was due to Turbolinks and I found the solution was to bind my event to the body and not the element, relevant answers are found in this thread:

[How to use $(document).on("click.. on <a tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338618/how-to-use-document-onclick-on-a-tag)

For me the problem was on clicking a label, so I had to change

`$('label').click(function...`

to

`$('body').on('click', 'label', function`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and finally understood the reason.
Your html source must be formed of as follows.

```
<tr>
  <form>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="submit"></td>
  </form>
</tr>
```

It seems some browsers including Chrome and Firefox cannot handle such nested tags correctly.

I could successfully submit rerendered forms after replacing table/tr/td tags with other ones like ul/li.

Comment: Note that your HTML here is entirely invalid. The `form` element cannot be a direct descendant of a `tr`.